# openMP - concurrent access to variables and atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

I want to parallelize with openMP a function that is sampling a box (selecting points randomly in a box, and evaluating a given function at these points). I wrote the following code.

```
//storing points
double** points_ = new double*[N-m];
for(int i=0;i<N-m;i++)
{
    points_[i]=new double[ndim];
}
double* evals_ = new double[N-m];

#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int i=0;i<N-m;i++)
{
    double* pt_ = randomPoint(lower,upper);
    for(int k=0;k<ndim;k++)
    {
        points_[i][k]=pt_[k];
    }
    evals_[i]=evalFunc(pt_);
    delete pt_;
}
```

However, I am not confident with this code: evals_ and points_ are updated in eauch thread. I think of adding some atomic statements there:

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int i=0;i<N-m;i++)
{
    double* pt_ = randomPoint(m_lower,m_upper);
    for(int k=0;k<m_ndim;k++)
    {
        #pragma omp atomic update
        points_[i][k]=pt_[k];
    }
    #pragma omp atomic update
    evals_[i]=evalFunc(pt_);
    delete pt_;
}
```

but I fear that this would be very unefficient: do you have some advice to write it more accurately? And... this is not compiling... (error: expression following #pragma omp atomic has improper form) althought I can find that examlpe in openMP specs, A22

```
void atomic_example(float *x, float *y, int *index, int n)
{
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(x, y, index, n)
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    #pragma omp atomic update
    x[index[i]] += work1(i);
    y[i] += work2(i);
    }
}
```

and atomic update is also followed here by an affectation to an array.

Thanks and regards.

EDIT--------

I agree with Tudor's answer. However, it seems that this example here, in another parallelized piece of code does need atomic: on line sum_+=..., an error occurs (concurrent access)

```
for(i=0;i<m_ndim;i++)
{
    double sum_=0;
    #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:sum_)
    for(j=0;j<m_npts;j++)
    {
        sum_ += set_[j][i];
    }
    Sum_[i] = sum_;
}
```

Why is it then needed? Or is smthing else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any atomic clauses in your code.

The reason is the fact that the outer loop is split over the index `i`, so each thread will get a set of elements from `points_` and `eval_` which do not overlap with another thread's working set.

`evals_` is an array, so each thread will get a contiguous subarray (due to the implicit static scheduling scheme), e.g.

```
0 1 2 3 . 4 5 6 7 . 8 9 10 11...
   t1        t2        t3
```

`points_` is a bidimensional matrix and each thread will get a contiguous set of rows:

```
   0 
   1
t1 2
   3
   .
   4
   5
t2 6
   7
   .
   8
   9
t3 10
   11
   ...
```

In this second case it would appear that you have an overlap on the value of `k`, because each thread has the same range for `k`, but the updated points fall on different rows (the index `i`), which, as shown above, do not overlap for different threads.

Comment: I agree! However, now I don't understnad why this other part of code (I edited my post above with this sample) is crashing, telling me that there is concurrent access in line `sum_+=set_[j][i]`. Thanks !

Comment: @dlib: Isn't that supposed to be `#pragma omp parallel for reduction...`? You seem to be missing the `for`, which gives a completely different semantic to the computation.